# Android save certain values on rotation

Tags: android, caching, android-asynctask, android-configchanges

I have an activity that runs asynctasks among other things, I don't want everything to be reset when the layout changes.

I put this in the activity's manifest element `android:configChanges="orientation"`  but unfortunately the activity doesn't even switch from the landscape to portrait layout anymore when that is there!

I only halfway understand saveInstanceStates and passing Bundles around, and I'm definitely not sure how to use that with complex data objects, insight appreciated there

What I would like to do is make sure that the asynctasks don't run again, (I could save variables to disk, and do a conditional check for them before running the asynctask) if there is some android way to really watch out for this that would be great!

thanks

Comment: Works for me!  Maybe you have something else blocking rotation, or perhaps it is delayed because your asynctask is running.

Comment: I'm sorry, what works for you? can you elaborate

Comment: So you only want to run the asnystask once..correct?

Comment: correct. when I rotate the device, the asynctasks run again

Comment: So do you want it to only run once PERIOD or just during the activities life cycle?

Comment: I am asking for details because i think i may have a solution

Comment: during the activity's life cycle. in this case, the one activity is the entire app.

Comment: @RD - configChanges allows my app to rotate during a download without interrupting my AsyncTask.  I also have keyboardHidden in there, I doubt that would make a difference but you might want to try it.  Can you post your manifest code?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this library will definitely serve your purpose

http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/11/16/introducing-droid-fu-for-android-betteractivity-betterservice-and-betterasynctask/

Answer (score 0):

When you put `android:configChanges="orientation"` in the manifest, you are declaring that android won't need to handle orientation change. Thus, the orientation never happens.

You can check out how to save value to bundle onConfigurationChange(in your case, orientation)  in this thread.[How do I save an Android application's state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state)

In brief, you save some value to bundle by overriding `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`. Retrieve the value you saved to bundle by either overriding `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` or checking bundle parameter at `onCreate`.

Comment: with `android:configChanges="orientation"` set, how would I force the layout to change due to rendering differneces in landscape and portrait, if I wanted to

Comment: @PH7 I don't think you are correct about this, my app does re-orient.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange 

This may help you more than I do. The catch is you need to override onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) and do what you would desire. Be cautious when you handle things by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to post what is working for me, is this what yours looks like?  This is from my manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MediaSelectActivity" 
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
android:label="Select Media Item for Vision"
 ></activity>
```

Comment: well I've had orientation before, but I do want the layout to change from portrait to landscape and vice versa. When I have that parameter in the activity, this no longer happens when I rotate the device (I didn't add extra classes like onConfigurationChanged though)

Comment: Do you have separate layouts for land and port?  Perhaps that would make a difference here.